# Focus in popup windows input field

Tags: jquery, popup, focus

I will like to make a pop-up with a very simple formular, but when it pop-up I will like to have FOCUS on the input field. That don't seem to work.

The code are form here: http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

Can you help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>ThickBox 3.1</title>
<style type="text/css" media="all">
@import "thickbox.css";
</style>

<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/1024.css" title="1024 x 768" />

<script src="jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="thickbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/global.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
            <p style="padding-top:10px"><input alt="#TB_inline?height=100&amp;width=300&amp;inlineId=myOnPageContent" onClick="document.getElementById('myControl').focus();" title="Type in new Bnumber" class="thickbox" type="button" value="Show" /> 
            <div id="myOnPageContent">
                <center>
                <br><br>
                <form name="input" action="" method="post">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>Username: </b> <input id="myControl" type="text" name="user" />
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr align="right">
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
                </center>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in the head of the file you put,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#firesPopup').click(function(){
         setTimeout($('#myControl').focus(), 1000);
    });
});
```

Does that now place the focus on the input field? Once you click on the button the fires the popup, it will wait 1 sec before it places the focus on the input field.

Comment: Yes it will do, but I need the focus when the button is pushed. Your suggestion is setting the focus when loading the page I think.

Comment: This works great. It is somthing with the setTimeout that was needed.
For clearn javascript use this:

function test2() {
 var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('myControl').focus()", 200);
}

<input id="firesPopup" onClick="test2()">